# Можно ли в Box2d использовать свою функцию отображения картинок?

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте.

Недавно узнал о Box2D и сразу же возникла проблема отрисовки картинок на экране телефона. В примерах Box2D используется OpenGL, что никак мне не подходит. У меня есть своя функция вывода картинки на экран: ее поворота, вообщем вывод и поворот. А можно как-нибудь перехватывать параметры: положение картинки на экране, угол ее поворота для передачи в свою функцию и соответственно вывода всего на экран? То есть Box2D всё пересчитывает, а я только вывожу. И еще, моя функция только выводит картинку(по x, y), обновляет ее (двигает) и поворачивает, а как я понял, в Box2D для всего используются полигоны. Это так? Вообщем можно вывести картинку на экран своей функцией?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то говоря, в этом и заключается смысл использования `Box2D`.

Вы, видимо, невнимательно прочитали [**Getting Started**](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) для библиотеки, которую вы собираетесь использовать *(где, кстати говоря, нет никакого упоминания о способах отрисовки).*

`Box2D` - это физический симулятор. Ему абсолютно параллельно на то, где, как, в какой момент и каким образом вы собираетесь что-либо отрисовывать, поскольку `Box2D` оперирует своими внутренними абстракциями, самыми базовыми из которых являются `b2Body` и `b2World`.

> - Простой сценарий использования - вы
>   добавляете в ваш мир (`b2World`)
>   несколько объектов (`b2Body`), задаете
>   им изначальные скорости, размеры,
>   `collision` параметры и говорите:
>   *"Уважаемый `b2World`! Проведите, пожалуйста, симуляцию и прикиньте,
>   каким вы будете через 0.1с."*
> - В коде
>   это может выглядеть как
>   `world->Step(0.1f).`
> - Далее вы в произвольный момент времени
>   можете обратиться к `world` и спросить
>   у него параметры всех `b2Body`,
>   который содержатся в нем, а именно
>   `GetPosition()`, `GetAngle()` и
>   [**некоторые другие.**](http://citrusengine.com/api/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.html)
> - **А зная эти параметры, вы можете проводить отрисовку полюбившимся вам
>   способом - хоть `ASCII` графикой в
>   консоли.**

Comment: Спасибо, я читал на русском...

Comment: А есть более подробное описание всего движка????